# Всегда получаю первое значение в select

Tags: javascript, select

Есть код:

```
<select name="cities" class ="order-input cities-names" id="city">
    <option value="gd1">Город 1</option>
    <option value="gd2">Город 2</option>
    <option value="gd3">Город 3</option>
    <option value="gd4">Город 4</option>
    <option value="gd5">Город 5</option>
    <option value="gd6">Город 6</option>
    <option value="other">Другой</option>
</select>
```

Мне надо выбранный город поместить в span.
Я достаю значение выбранного option и помещаю в span с id = user_city_label:

```
var selectedCity = $("#city option:selected").text();
    document.getElementById("user_city_label").innerHTML = selectedCity;
```

Но приходит всегда значение первого option, то есть Город 1.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо отслеживать изменение поля `select`. 
Сейчас у Вас происходит получение данных при загрузке страницы.
Пример:

```js
    $('#city').on('change', function () {
        var selectedCity = $("#city option:selected").text();
        document.getElementById("user_city_label").innerHTML = selectedCity;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cities" class ="order-input cities-names" id="city">
    <option value="gd1">Город 1</option>
    <option value="gd2">Город 2</option>
    <option value="gd3">Город 3</option>
    <option value="gd4">Город 4</option>
    <option value="gd5">Город 5</option>
    <option value="gd6">Город 6</option>
    <option value="other">Другой</option>
</select>
<span id="user_city_label"></span>
```

Так же если Вы работаете в `jquery`, лучше делайте всё через него, не смешивая `js` и `jquery`. 
Так Вам будет проще работать в дальнейшем. 
Пример на `jquery`:

```js
    $('#city').on('change', function () {
        var selectedCity = $("#city option:selected").text();
        $('#user_city_label').text(selectedCity);
    }).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cities" class ="order-input cities-names" id="city">
    <option value="gd1">Город 1</option>
    <option value="gd2">Город 2</option>
    <option value="gd3">Город 3</option>
    <option value="gd4">Город 4</option>
    <option value="gd5">Город 5</option>
    <option value="gd6">Город 6</option>
    <option value="other">Другой</option>
</select>
<span id="user_city_label"></span>
```

Comment: `$('#city').on('change', function () { ... }).change();`

Comment: @Igor Хорошее замечание, спасибо. Добавил во второй вариант.